# Custom View in xib not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, xib

I have [VPMOTPView](https://github.com/varunpm1/VPMOTPView) custom view in my `.xib' like this.
[image]

```
class VerifyOTP: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var otpView: VPMOTPView!

    var emailID = ""
    var userID = ""

    @IBAction func resendOTPAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("asdds")
    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        otpView.otpFieldsCount = 4
        otpView.otpFieldDefaultBorderColor = UIColor.blue
        otpView.otpFieldEnteredBorderColor = UIColor.red
        otpView.otpFieldBorderWidth = 2
        otpView.delegate = self

        // Create the UI
        otpView.initalizeUI()

    }

}

extension VerifyOTP: VPMOTPViewDelegate {
    func hasEnteredAllOTP(hasEntered: Bool) {
        print("Has entered all OTP? \(hasEntered)")
    }

    func enteredOTP(otpString: String) {
        print("OTPString: \(otpString)")
    }
}
```

Then in my 'ViewController'

```
var verifyOTPView: VerifyOTP?
   self.verifyOTPView = VerifyOTP.fromNib()
    self.verifyOTPView?.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: screenSize.width - 40, height: screenSize.height / 3)
    self.view.addSubview(self.verifyOTPView!)
```

But by this I can see my RESEND OTP button on screen but OTPVIEW is not displayed.

Comment: Did you set its class to respective class in storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot it doesn't look like you have any constraints set up for your views?

If not try adding constraints and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Damn awesome observation. Thanks. :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help 